# Unable to resolve TRISBbits even with xc.h included

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pic, c, mplabx

I am new to PIC programming, and I am trying to blink an LED using the PIC32CM MC00. I understand I must declare them as inputs or outputs, but the IDE I am using (MPLAB) keeps giving me an error when I declare the TRIS register. Attached is a picture and code.

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <p32xxxx.h>

#if defined(__32CM1216MC00032__) || defined(__PIC32CM1216MC00032__)
# include <proc/PIC32CM1216MC00032/pic32cm1216mc00032.h>
#endif

// Function to introduce a delay
void delay(int milliseconds) {
    for (int i = 0; i < milliseconds; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16000; j++) {} // Adjust for your clock speed
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // Set LED pin (RB5) as an output
    TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 0;

    while (1) {
        // Turn on the LED
        LATBbits.LATB5 = 1;

        // Delay for 1 second
        delay(1000);

        // Turn off the LED
        LATBbits.LATB5 = 0;

        // Delay for 1 second
        delay(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

The issue doesnt seem to be the xc.h as its not showing an error. Amy help would be much appreciated.

Comment: From what I can see in PIC32CM MC00 datasheet. This uC does not have LATx and TRISx registers. Also, 32-pin version also does not have PORTB, thus PB5 does not exist as well. And from what I see this PIC is using AVR-style (SAM) registers names nomenclature.  Thus, we have for example PORTA.DIR registers to configure I/O pins as an input or output. And PORTA.OUT to set pin high or low.

Comment: Hi there, I really appreciate both of your assistance with this. I'm kind of new to embedded programming, so your help means a lot. I'm trying to set the LED pin on the board as an output, and I believe I should write PA23 followed by a .DIRSET to make the direction register 1. However, I'm encountering an error related to PA23. Is there something I'm overlooking or didn't include that's causing this error? Thanks again!

Comment: The PIC32C... is powered with an ARM cortex, and the PIC32M... is powered by MIPS. Only the PIC32 MIPS controller work with `LATTx`and `TRISx`register, so you had to look for an ARM based example. And don't double include your header, `#include <xc.h>`is enough.

Comment: @G36 Why do you add your own comment into the question?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, LATx and TRISx registers are not defined for the device you use. That's probably why MPLAB is giving you errors. Preprocessor commands coming with the device definitions may `#define` and/or `#undef` the register definitions.

See the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC32CM-MC00-Family-Data-Sheet-DS60001638D.pdf) and library documents or source files for details and try to find examples specifically for your device and device family, such as [this one](https://github.com/Microchip-MPLAB-Harmony/csp_apps_pic32cm_mc00/tree/master/apps/port/port_led_on_off_polling).

Comment: From what I can see in  PIC32CM MC00 datasheet.  This uC does not have LATx and TRISx registers. Also 32-pin version also does not have PORTB, thus PB5 does not exist as well.

Comment: Hi there, I really appreciate both of your assistance with this. I'm kind of new to embedded programming, so your help means a lot. I'm trying to set the LED pin on the board as an output, and I believe I should write PA23 followed by a .DIRSET to make the direction register 1.   
However, I'm encountering an error related to PA23. Is there something I'm overlooking or didn't include that's causing this error? Thanks again!"

Answer (score 0):

As I said earlier your PIC32CM MC00 is more like a AVR SAM uC.
Not a 32-bit PIC. Thus, your uC does not have LATx and TRISx registers at all.

So, to blink an LED at PA23 you need to use this code (the AVR style) instead:

```c
#include <Xc.h>

#define GROUP_NUMBER 0  //PORTA is a GROUP 0, PORTB GROUP 1 ... 

int main(void)
{
    
    /* Set the PIN23 as an OUTPUT */
     PORT_REGS->GROUP[GROUP_NUMBER].PORT_DIRSET = PORT_PA23;

    while (1)
    {
        PORT_REGS->GROUP[GROUP_NUMBER].PORT_OUTTGL = PORT_PA23; //Toggle PIN PA23
            //Delay 
            for(uint32_t i=0; i <= 10000000; i++)  // Adjust for your clock speed
            {
                __ASM("NOP");
            }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```